# Showing that a derivative is locally continuous

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-writing

I am trying to complete the following (seemingly simple) proof, and I'm a little stuck at one point. I would like either help getting over this hump or suggestions about how else to approach the problem. Here goes:

Suppose $f'(x), g'(x)$ exist, $g'(x) \neq 0$, and $f(x) = g(x) = 0$. Prove that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow x} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

It seems like this should be a fairly straight forward application of L'hopital's rule.

**My attempt at a solution**:

Because $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ exist, $f(t), g(t)$ are each continuous at $x$, and thus $\lim_{t \rightarrow x} = 0$, and likewise for $g$.

Here is where I need help: I need to show that $lim_{t \rightarrow x} f'(t) = f'(x)$, but I can't think of way to do it. **I do know the following though**:

```
1) Derivatives obey the intermediate value property
2) Derivatives cannot have jump discontinuities
```

Once I have found a way to show that these limits are correct, then I can say that for some small neighborhood around $x$, $f'(t), g'(t) \neq 0$.

Once I have shown this, all of the criteria for L'Hopital's rule will be met and I can proceed from there. Any suggestions or alternative pathways?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say that $f'(x)$ exists, do you mean for *every* $x$? Just asking because you also take $\lim_{t\to x}$ ...

Comment: No; $x$ is a point in the domain; the independent variable is $t$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your assumptions, this version of l'Hopital is easy to prove:

$$ \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} =  \frac{f(t)-0}{g(t)-0} =  \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{g(t)-g(x)} =  \frac{ \ \ \frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\ \ }{\ \  \frac{g(t)-g(x)}{t-x}\ \ } \xrightarrow[t→ x]{} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$
Where the limiting step is by quotient rule for limits: we can apply this since the numerator and denominators individually have limits by virtue of $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ existing, and also $g'(x)≠0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we need differentiability *only* at $x$:
$$\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}}{\frac {g(t)-g(x)}{t-x}}=\frac{\lim_{t\to x}\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}}{\lim_{t\to x}\frac{g(t)-g(x)}{t-x}} =\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$

Comment: That first equality is tricky! It took me a few minutes to follow why this was permissible.